# Probability Theory question P(at most)

Tags: probability

A certain type of pen has three features A, B and C. P(A) = 0.55, P(B) = 0.45 and P(C) = 0.4, P(A∩B)=0.25, P(A∩C)=0.2 , P(B∩C)=0.15 and P(A∩B∩C)=0.1

Question: Find the probability that a customer will ask for at most two of the options.

My work: Initially I assumed [P(A∩B)+P(A∩C)+P(B∩C)-2P(A∩B∩C)] = 0.45 will get me the answer --
Turns out, this idea is wrong, and simply doing [1 - P(A∩B∩C)] = 0.9 will get you the correct answer.

I am a bit unclear on this idea and would like to understand how 0.9 is the correct answer to the given statement and not 0.45

Thank you.

Comment: The title and body text are at odds. Were you asked for "at least", or "at most" ?

Comment: At most means zero, one or two which is the same as everything but three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event of *at **least** two* is $(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$.

The probability for this is $${\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(B\cap C)-2\,\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)\\=0.25+0.20+0.15-2\cdot0.10 \\=0.40}$$

---

$1-\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)$ is the probability for the event of *at **most** two* (ie: *not all three*).

Comment: Were you asked for "at least" or "at most"?

Comment: At most. I’m sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Since now I know the p(at most) and I wish to find out the p(exactly two) can I simply say —> -(0.25+0.2+0.15) + 0.9 = 0.3

Comment: Numerically, yes, but what are you counting?   *Exactly two* is *at least two and not all three*.$${\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(B\cap C)-3\,\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)]\\=(0.25+0.20+0.15)-3\cdot0.10\\=0.30}$$

Answer (score 0):

At most two options includes one option also. You did not take into account the possibility of a sigle option being chosen.